# IIS response time in logs different from C# stopwatch

Tags: c#, iis, stopwatch

I try to measure the response time of my Webservice with this code, and I have very strange results if I compare it to IIS logs.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
{
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;

    using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data))
    {
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed {sw.TotalMilliseconds}ms");
    }
}
```

This code can measure 30ms where IIS will say 90ms.
Sometimes this code and IIS will have the same value.

Can anyone explain why the value differs?

Comment: It is hard to say why it happens now. Could you also show the IIS-side code? What type of web application is this?

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't :( Do you have any clue on what could make this values differents